# How do I terminate a specific JobFlow in Amazon EMR?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have one job flow, and it's "KeepAlive" value is set to true. When I run it, it naturally starts an EMR cluster.

My goal is to terminate this cluster entirely. I assume this is done using a TerminateJobFlowRequest, which requires some JobFlowIDs to work.

This is problematic for two reasons:

1) [These](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduce.html) docs say the "describeJobFlows" method is deprecated and suggests no alternative.

2) Describing all job flows gives me all the recent job flows on my account. I'd prefer to receive only the info for the job flows attached to the current AmazonEMRClient.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to find my specific JobFlow and terminate it? Please and thank you.

Comment: listClusters() is the replacement you seek

Comment: @JudgeMental Thank you. I'm going to experiment with that now.

Comment: @JudgeMental This appears to not be so helpful, sadly. :( listClusters() allows me to get the cluster ID (in an inelegant way), but I don't see how I can terminate the cluster using a cluster's ID (crazy I know). Any ideas how to terminate the cluster using this info?

Comment: How do you want to find the cluster, if not by ID?  I think you are misunderstanding how the client works.  It (the client) is not stateful; the particular instance of the client that you used to start a cluster does not maintain any association with that cluster.

Comment: Because even if I had the cluster, I see no method for terminating a cluster, only a JobFlow. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for that. Will keep experimenting. With that in mind, I should mark the answer given as correct, as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
emrClient.terminateJobFlows(
    new TerminateJobFlowsRequest().withJobFlowIds( strId )
);
```

Comment: what if termination protection is enabled on the cluster?